# perl - system command arguments give error

Tags: perl, shell, command, system

Tried hard to find a solution for this. But I probably need some help. I am trying to pass a bunch of arguments in system command in perl. But I get an irrelevant error. I have my variables correctly declared with the right scope and still get this error below. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $mi = 0;
my $mj = 0;

my @regbyte;
my @databyte;
my $filename;
my @args;
@regbyte =       ("00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","0A","0B","0C","0D","0E","0F","10","11","12");
@databyte = ("00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09", "0A", "0B");

for($mi=0; $mi<13; $mi++)
{
for($mj=0; $mj<256; $mj++)
    {
        $filename = "write_" . $regbyte[$mi] . "_" . $databyte[$mj] . ".atp";   
        system("perl perl_2_ver2.5.pl",  $filename, $regbyte[$mi],     $databyte[$mj], "n");
    }
}
```

This is the error message I get.

```
Global symbol "$databyte" requires explicit package name at perl_2_ver2.8.pl     line 20.
Execution of perl_2_ver2.8.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: I don't get the same error when I try and verify your code. Are you sure it's reproduced verbatim? 

Also - I think you have a logic error. You iterate 256 elements of @databyte, but it doesn't have that many elements. (A foreach loop might be more apt for what you're doing anyway)

Comment: Is the script you show us the `perl_2_ver2.8.pl` script?  If not, you're not showing the relevant Perl code.  If it is, why are you 'recursing' by executing the script again?  You can eliminate `@args` and could (should) initialize `@regbyte` and `@databyte` in the line you define them.  All of `$mi`, `$mj` and `$filename` could be given a much smaller scope than you have.

Comment: The error message that you show doesn't correspond to the Perl source code. Line 20 is your `system` call, but you aren't accessing a variable called `$databyte` -- you are accessing just an element of the array `@databyte`, which wouldn't produce that error message.

Answer (score 2):

I'm puzzled about a few things, in particular the trailing `"n"` you have in your `system` call. Is that supposed to be `"\n"`? Because it's unnecessary and wrong in that context.

The main problem is that you have

```
for ( $mj = 0; $mj < 256; $mj++ ) { .. }
```

and then access `$databyte[$mj]` when `@databyte` has only twelve elements. It's hard to know what you might mean.

Here's how I would write something that works, but may not be your intention.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'FATAL';

for my $regbyte (0 .. 0x12) {
    for my $databyte (0 .. 0x0B) {
        my $filename = sprintf "write_%02X_%02X.atp", $regbyte, $databyte;
        system("perl perl_2_ver2.5.pl $filename $regbyte $databyte");
    }
}
```

It looks like you want to run your script `perl_2_ver2.5.pl` with input consisting of all files that look like `write_*_*.atp`. Is that right?

Unless the directory contains `atp` files that you *don't* want to process, you are probably better off using just

```
while (my $filename = glob 'write*.atp') {
    next unless /\Awrite_(\p{hex}{2})_(\p{hex}{2}).atp\z/;
    system("perl perl_2_ver2.5.pl $filename $1 $2");
}
```

which just processes all the files that *do* exist and match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted your code and only replaced the program parameter for the `system` call and I do not get the error you are reporting. However there are many array elements accessed, that don't exist.

You can limit your loops using the arraysizes like this:

```
for($mi=0; $mi<$#regbyte; $mi++)
```

And I believe you have two alternatives for your system call, either `perl_2_ver2.5.pl` is executable, then you can say (supposed, same directory):

```
system("./perl_2_ver2.5.pl",  $filename, $regbyte[$mi],    $databyte[$mj], "n");
```

Or you have to call:

```
system("perl" , "./perl_2_ver2.5.pl",  $filename, $regbyte[$mi],    $databyte[$mj], "n");
```

Comment: Erm ... but you haven't seen the program invoked by `system`!

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it? The error message is from the program shown.

Comment: You say you have *"made changes only to the program invoked by `system`"*, but you haven't seen the code of that program, so how can you have made changes to it?

Comment: Meant to say to what was called.

Comment: Okay but that means the same thing. Do you mean *"I have made changes to only the parameters of the `system` call"*?

Comment: Exactly - sorry for the confusion.